# OpenCV simple blob detector not working

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to detect centers of circles in image in all color channels separately. My code looks something like this:

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
//#include "features2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

Mat imageSource;

Mat colorChannels[3];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
    params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 50;
    params.filterByArea = true;
    params.minArea = 50000;

    params.filterByColor = true;
    params.blobColor = 255;

    Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create();
    imageSource = imread("opencv-logo.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    split(imageSource, colorChannels);

    threshold(colorChannels[1], colorChannels[1], 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    bitwise_not(colorChannels[1], colorChannels[1]);
    detector->detect(colorChannels[1], keypoints);

    int number = keypoints.size();

    printf("%d\n", number);

    namedWindow("Original", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Original", colorChannels[1]);

    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

But every time I try to run it, different vector size is output, like -592369722 or 1062631863 - nothing normal. Tried to play with parameters of blobdetector, but outcome is the same. If I try to uncomment `#include "features2d.hpp"`, whole program just crashes.
My OpenCV version is 3.4.1.
How can I fix this?

Comment: With v3, I think you can drop all OpenCV-related `#includes` except the third one you list.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you for respond, but it's still not working.

Comment: You haven't `#included <vector>`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, nope, still the same.

Comment: Maybe set `params.maxArea` to something sensible too.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, that's not the case. I even tried to just ctrl+c and ctrl+v some code from internet, that should be working, but it isn't. Could it be problems with my installation or version of OpenCV? If I don't use blob detector, everything is just fine.