# Blob detector crashes kernel or dies

Tags: python, opencv

cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()causes kernel to crash and python to stop when running a jupyter notebook using a anaconda3 python 3 and open cv 4.1.1

[image]

Comment: Could you state the full error message?

Comment: Hi, On the browser it says python stopped working then it gives me an option to debug then when I press debug it takes me to Visual Studio I have now added a picture of the error from VS on my original question.Please have a look

Comment: please provide more information.

Comment: What kind of information

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124851/opencv-simple-blob-detector-not-working (no answer there either)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
```

instead of:

```
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the error message in that image, it looks like an opencv path problem. You might need to add opencv to your path then restart. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775060/4703367